# ReactJs Ajax Get

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm trying to get a normal ajax get call to be executed within a reactJs component with the onClick of a button. When I try with my following code nothing happens, but the api is live and is working. It doesn't even log anything to the browser console. What is it that I am doing wrong ? I am new to reactjs so I do apologize. I'm using reactJS.net with mvc 5 and web api 2. Im just seeing if I can hit a webapi v2 function via its route. The route itself works fine on its own and I am able to trigger the break point but not from the reactJs onClick event

```
var HomeReact = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        welcomeMsg: this.props.welcomeMsg,
    };
},

testApi: function () {
    console.log("Clicking");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/reg/testapi",
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("fail - " + error);
        }

    });
},

render() {
    return (
        <div id="welcomeHolder" align="center">
            {this.state.welcomeMsg}
            <br />
            <button onClick={this.testApi}>React Learning Api Test</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

Comment: `console.log("Clicking");` is printing the clicking in console?

Comment: try `onClick={this.testApi.bind(this)}`

Comment: No unfortunately not printing to the console.

Comment: onClick={this.testApi.bind(this)} this doesn't seem to work either. Strangely enough the model binding works though when the page is rendered and I bind to this  {this.state.welcomeMsg} just cant get this onclick event to trigger

Comment: check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/55ev3m87/ clicking is printed in console properly, check where you are doing the mistake.

Comment: I get document is undefined when I try your code

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your api. If you use working url `"https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json",` it will work.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
      
      this.state = {
       welcomeMsg: "Welcome message"
      }
    }
    
    testApi(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json",
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
          },
          error: function (error) {
              alert("fail - " + error);
          }

      });
    }
    
  render(){
     return (
       <div id="welcomeHolder" align="center">
            {this.state.welcomeMsg}<br />
            <button onClick={this.testApi.bind(this)}>React Learning Api Test</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2877/)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, this is a .net issue im pretty sure of it. as the code I used from your above snippet returns an error of document is undefined. Im pretty sure its got to do with MVC and the fact I'm rendereing the react in the mvc view

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must give complete url in ajax call
like this

url: "http://localhost:666/api//reg/testapi",